# Redis Lua script for search by score and some specific attibute in the value

Tags: redis, lua

I have a Zset where i wanted to search with certain score range and value contains sepcifix object.
IT would be a bi zset so wanted to avoid zscan
Like in below screen it should return me records with "txnId":1 in value
is it possible

[image]

I know i can use Zscan command like
ZSCAN Zset 0 MATCH *"txnId":"1"*
but it doesn't even take score to filter out searching in particular items. so these scan will be run on all items as per my thinking and will create bottleneck

Comment: it seems to be not there yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic answer is at the moment of time till redis 6.0 this is not possible